# PHP- unserialize to an object

Tags: php

Is there any similar PHP function that can unserialize to an object instead of always to an array?

```
$session_data = unserialize($tmp[0]); // I need this to be an object
```

I need to unserialize to an object so I can access values like `$session_data->FirstName` instead of `$session_data['FirstName']`.

EDIT: I have a function that will do this, but to me it seems sloppy and I was wondering if there was a way of doing this natively within PHP:

```
function ato($array) {
    $obj= new stdClass();
    foreach ($array as $k=> $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $v = array_to_object($v);
        }
        $obj->{strtolower($k)} = $v;
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

Comment: Yes read the `serialize()` documentation. If you serialize an object you can use the data to unserialize the same object

Comment: This has been answered in full here: Can you create instance properties dynamically in PHP?

Short summary. You can either use a class constructor method to dynamically generate properties with an associative array or you can use magic methods to customize your setter and getter methods to do the same on a name-by-name basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$foo = [
    'bar'  => 'baz',
];
$foo = (object)$foo;
echo $foo->bar;
```

Comment: True, but I think this does exactly what the OP wants. @RiggsFolly Don't you?

Comment: You might be right, but its not what he said he wanted